# Uniform convergent and lipschitz continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, functions

I want to prove that if I have a sequence $ f_n\in C[0,1]$ that is uniform convergent to zero and all functions are lipschitz continuous, then the lipschitz constants form a zero sequence. Does anybody here know to show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true.

If I take $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sin (n^2x)$, then $f_n$ converges to zero uniformly, each $f_n$ is Lipschitz continuous, but the Lipschitz constants are $L_n = n$ (since $\sup_{x \in [0,1]} f_n'(x) = n$).